# Are there available tools to manage kubernetes configuration?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, amazon-eks

Given a container in a Azure container registry and a kubernetes cluster setup via the portal. Are there any visual tools that I can use so that I **don't have to use the command line commands** ,for things like add/edit the yaml file and launching the cluster?

For example I found this tool https://k8syaml.com/, but this is only one part of the process and it is also not aware of the existing infrastructure.

What are the visual tools to manage kubernetes end-to-end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One tool I always work with when dealing with Kubernetes is [Lens](https://k8slens.dev/desktop.html). [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eeDwdVXattc) is a video showing you what it can do. Best of all, it just needs the kube config file and so it is agnostic to where the Kubernetes cluster is (On-Prem, GKE, AKS, EKS)

Answer (score 1):

[kubectx](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx) for switching between contexts (clusters) & [K9s](https://k9scli.io/) is widely used that is something hybrid between being a cli and visual tool.

Answer (score 1):

Octant is another option - https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/octant, it is similar to lens